# How to quickly build a two dimensional array from two arrays using FP or 3rd party library

Tags: java

I have two double arrays `x[], y[]` with equal dimension, how to quickly build a double array without loops

Double `xy[][]` from x, y with the second dimension be 2.

I am OK with using any third part libraries

code using loops

```
 double xy[][] = new double[x.length][2];
 for (int i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
            xy[i][0] = x[i];
            xy[i][1] = y[i];
 }
```

To be frank, I do not like the above code. I wish there is some FP way to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a tensor product?  xy[i][j] = (x[i]*y[j])  Why do you need a library?

Comment: Loops. Thats all you need.

Comment: Doesn't have to be N x N; can be M x N.

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what "building" xy means? If xy has dimensions equal to len(x), len(y), then it contains len(x)*len(y) elements, but you only have len(x)+len(y). What are you supposed to fill the array with?

Comment: Then the matrix will be N x N.

Comment: Loops is all you need AND it will be the fastest.

Comment: If you have 10 elements in x, 10 elements in y, you can't create a 10*10 table! You would need 100 elements, not 20!

Comment: make it clear in the original post

Comment: for example, if length of x and y are both 10, I need to create an array of 10,2, is it clear to everyone now?

Comment: What have your tried (e.g. using a loop)? And where are you stucked?

Comment: I don't like loops, too ugly in this case. wondering any elegant solution.

Comment: "too ugly"?  I'd write the code and move on.

Comment: code is easy, but I feel ugly, let me post the original code

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. If you look for an online tutorial on working with arrays and matrices in Java you will probably find it helpful for whatever you've got coming next.

```
public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x[] = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0};
        double y[] = {3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

        double xy[][]= new double[2][];
        xy[0] = new double[x.length];
        xy[1] = new double[y.length];

        for (int i=0 ; i < x.length ;i++)
            xy[0][i] = x[i];
        for (int j=0 ; j < y.length ;j++)
            xy[1][j] = y[j];

        for (int i=0 ; i < xy.length ;i++) {
            for (int j=0 ; j < xy[i].length ;j++) {
                System.out.print(xy[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0 
3.0 4.0 5.0
```

Comment: You do not need two loops since `x.length == y.length`.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is write the following line
`double[][] xy = {x, y};`

Comment: Well, that's sweet, I didn't know you could do that. File that one away for another day....

Comment: some new to me, I like this

Comment: However the solution here is just opposite what I need. for example, it have xy[0][9], xy[1][9], but what I want is xy[9][0], xy[9][1]

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way will be either what you have written, or this:

```
    double xy[][] = new double[x.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
        xy[i] = new double[]{x[i], y[i]};
    }
```

Now you could also do this:

```
    double xy[][] = {x, y};
```

However that is creating an N x 2 array rather than a 2 x N array.  Furthermore, the `x` and `y` arrays have now been *incorporated* into the `xy` array.  That is semantically different to your version (and mine) where the arrays `x` and `y` will be distinct from `xy`.

---

> To be frank, I do not like the above code. I wish there is some FP way to solve this problem.

Well, there probably is a way to code this using streams, but it is unlikely to be quicker / more efficient than a simple loop.  Or at least, not in Java 8.

Here's one possible solution (not tested!):

```
   double[][] xy = IntStream.range(0, x.length - 1)
         .map(lambda i: new double[]{x[i], y[i]})
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
         .toArray(new double[0][0]);
```

Comment: I am not worry too much on efficiency, I like to use Java8 if I can. Could you show me how to do this?